# Range gets deleted when reassigned

Tags: vba, range, declaration

Hi I am new to VBA and was wondering why is it that when I reset my range, everything within the range deletes. Are we not supposed to reassign ranges in VBA? The line that is having a problem is `supervisor_range = .Range(Cells(2, 1), .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp))` All the names in the image below get deleted.

[image]

```
Sub remove()
    Dim supervisorsheet As Worksheet
    Set supervisorsheet = Worksheets("supervisor")
    
    Dim supervisor_range As Range
    Dim cell As Range
    
    last_row = supervisorsheet.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row
    
    Set supervisor_range = supervisorsheet.Range(Cells(2, 1), Cells(last_row, 1))
    supervisor_range.RemoveDuplicates Columns:=1, Header:=xlNo
    
    With supervisorsheet        
        supervisor_range = .Range(Cells(2, 1), .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

This

```
supervisor_range = .Range(Cells(2, 1), .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
```

does not set the variable `supervisor_range` to the given range. Instead you copy the values of the range into the range that is referenced by `supervisor_range`.

If you want to set the variabe to the range then you need to use the keyword `Set`

```
Set supervisor_range = .Range(Cells(2, 1), .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
```

without `Set` the following 2 lines are identical!

```
supervisor_range = .Range(Cells(2, 1), .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
supervisor_range.Value = .Range(Cells(2, 1), .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp)).Value
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition to existing answer, I am not fully clear why you do what you do - defining the range of cels, maniuplating it, defining it again...

Here's simplified version of your code, which does exactly what it should - removes duplicates from given range:

```
Sub remove()

    Dim supervisorsheet As Worksheet
    Set supervisorsheet = Worksheets("supervisor")
    
    Dim supervisor_range As Range
    
    With supervisorsheet
        last_row = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    
        Set supervisor_range = .Range(Cells(2, 1), Cells(last_row, 1))
        supervisor_range.RemoveDuplicates Columns:=1, Header:=xlNo
    End With
End Sub
```